# Issue in mass updating a custom object records with an activated process flow

Tags: process-builder

I have a custom object " Quotation" with some field values i have taken on the detailed page from its child object " Car". I have used process builder for that on the child object " Car".
Now, i want to update values on a field in the object " car", i used the data loader ( as well as from view mode in SF on Car object) , but everytime it shows errors, showing a process flow exists and failed to trigger", when i deactivated the PB i can update , But i cant , as i simultaneously need to update the field values in the " Quotation" object. I can't deactivate the PB.

For making the vallues auto populate in the Quotation object, i need to have the mass update on the child Car object. Can anyone plz let me know why i am getting an update error while a PB exists and how to fix this, Thanks

Comment: everytime the PB fails you get an email from salesforce that is the log of the error you can debug from that. Secondly can you share the conditions that you have listed to trigger the PB?

Comment: Hi Sagar, Sure, I got the below errormessage.                                                  An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate).
UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK) Record rolled back because not all records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header --- for SFDC record with ID : a02280000096mibAAA

Comment: What are the conditions that trigger this PB? And do you have any apex trigger defined on the same object?

Comment: Its showing not all records are valid, But i think it should show me error only when the relared records not valid, and rest should be success, isnt it. Also, in my Data loader setting the batch size showing 200. Is that somthing to do with this ? Do i have to chaange the batch size? I couldnt understand the batch size number, If aanything to do with this ?

Comment: The records are not getting saved from data loader as you have active process builder process defined. If the conditions are not met by PB during data loader upload the error ( records are not vaild) will be thrown. Can you share you entry criteria of Process Builder, I suspect your records are not qualifying the Process Builder's conditions.

Comment: No, i dont have any apex trigger, below are the PB logic on Car object, it updates the below field value from Car object to the parent Quotation object. Car make ( this is the field from the Quotation object) > reference> [Car__c].Car_Make__c ( this is the reference to the child Car object), Similarly another two Car Model & Car Year ( from quotation ) reference to field value from the child Car object. Thanks

Comment: What is the entry criteria? ( How does record qualifies to be part of this PB process )

Comment: Ohh, Thanks. But isnt it, if some criteria not satisfying it should throw errors on those and rest it should upload ? Or, even if certain fields not satisfied , it will throw issue for all i.e even teh records satisfying the criteria ? how can i make that it will upload the records which met and throw errors which not met, anything to be done from setting side ? If i need to change the batch size in data loader setting ? ( currently 200)

Comment: Entry criteria, i just put " No criteria, just execute the action"

Comment: The approach is all or none. If you read your debug logs its clear from that - UPDATE --- UPDATE FAILED --- ERRORS : (ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK, you can try to change the batch size from data data loader settings and make it one( 1) , the similar solution is listed here - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063000000158YeAAI

Comment: Thanks Sagar, I chaanged it to 1 and it worked. So Is that batch size 200 means, it was updating either All 200 or none ? and making it 1 means it will check one by one ? Is that what batch size means, if you can explain a bit on the batch size plz.

Comment: This is part of salesforce governor limits. In a single insert, update, upsert, or delete operation, records moving to or from Salesforce are processed in increments of this size. The maximum value is 10,000 if the Use Bulk API option is selected.

Comment: I have provided the reason to your problem and solution if you find the answer accurate and it has solved your problem please mark it as solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is already raised for solution on IdeaExchange https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lEPRQA2

If any of the record fails the Active Process in Process Builder all the records are rolled back , that is because there is no option to deactivate the AllOrNone flag. 
 Best is to make your data load batch size to 1 and it will resolve your issue.